# Using gerund vs. of-phrase: Which is natural?

Tags: sentence-construction, difference

Consider these sentences:

> 1) To make selecting values easier we've added a new style dropdown.
>
> 2) To make the selection of the values easier we've added a new style dropdown.

Which is recommended? Why?

Comment: There is no infinitive (except 'make') in the second sentence.  "The selection" is a ***noun***.

Comment: As a general rule, if two choices are equally correct, then the shorter choice is usually preferable.

Comment: @VictorBazarov it is a noun derived from the verb "select", what are they called?

Comment: @Ahmad: A noun.

Comment: FWIW,  "a new style *of* dropdown" sounds better to me. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=new+style+car%2C+new+style+of+car&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnew%20style%20of%20car%3B%2Cc0

Comment: *"it is a noun derived from the verb "select", what are they called?"* - if I recall correctly, they are called **[deverbal nouns](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/78265/48335)**

Comment: is the dropdown used to select "style"? That would be a _new Style dropdown_.  Or Is the dropdown itself restyled? That would be a _new-style dropdown_.

Comment: The term you want is 'derivative noun' or 'derived noun'. A 'deverbal noun' is a noun which still has the form of a verb (typically a gerund) but has lost its verbal properties: it does not take objects or other complements, it is modified with adjectives rather than adverbs, and  it takes determiners.

Comment: @StoneyB : So, is 'selection' a *deverbal noun*?  Or is it a *derivative noun*?  Or are those different names of the same concept?

Comment: @VictorBazarov It is a derivative noun. In 'the easy selecting of values', *selecting* is a deverbal noun.

Comment: @StoneyB : Thanks.  Still unclear.  Article on DVN on Wikipedia says that DVNs do not take objects.  In "selection of values" 'values' seems an object, doesn't it?

Comment: @VictorBazarov In the English grammatical tradition we distinguish the thematic function 'Patient' from the syntactic function 'Object'. *Values* is the Patient of *selection*, but syntactically it is not an Object of *selection* but the object of the preposition *of*--the PP expresses the thematic relationship.